# кидать char в string

Tags: c++, строки, char

возможно ли кидать в string поэлементно char, чтобы строка "обрастала" символами? Если да, то как?

моя попытка, но она не работает (строка остается пустой, с размерами всё в порядке

```
for (int i = 0; i < _size; ++i)
{
    if (prior(_stackArray[i]) >= prior(elem))
    {
        str += _stackArray[i];
        del(_stackArray[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: А какой язык? Надо в метках указать.

Comment: В java, javascript, c# такое точно работает, про другие языки сказать не могу.

Comment: Приведите [минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), а то с таким огрызком ничего не ясно. Добавлять символы можно либо `str += c;` либо через `push_back`.

Answer (score 1):

Возможно, для вашей задачи (динамически собирать строки) больше подойдет `std::stringstream` (`#include <sstream>`):

```
std::stringstream s;
s << 's' << 'p' << 'a' << 'm';
std::string str = s.str();
```

Comment: Ну, это уже из серии "зачем просто, если можно сложно?"...

Comment: @Harry , есть такое, но, по-моему, пусть лучше сразу знакомится со стандартными инструментами.

Comment: Ну, если бы ему нужно было *разнотипные* вещи кидать - я бы не спорил. А для `char` - `push_back`, возможно, с резервированием памяти для эффективности.

Comment: всё верно, предлагаю @VTT дать ответ.